# is there any way to get recently added N items from firebase storage in javascript?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I am using Firebase Storage in a project but facing one issue that is I want to fetch only the last N number of items (that are recently added ones) from firebase storage is there any way to do so?

one way I saw over the internet is using the list function which returns results using offset and limit but again one problem exists with that function that is I have to retrieve all files then I will reach to last n files this sounds ok at first glance but if data is too much it can make the system slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution that I can see, would be to store the URL of the file along with the timestamp of the upload operation in a database like [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/products/firestore). If you for example need to get the recently `n` uploaded files then you can simply perform a query in Firestore and order the results descending by timestamp and limit to results to `n`. In this way, you'll be able to read only a fixed number of files and not all the files that exist at a particular location in Storage.

Comment: Yeah, that can be a way but again need additional space to maintain everything. But yeah will solve the problem.